# How to call function of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I put the following codes in an external .js file, but i tried to call the function, it returns undefined. Plz help

```
   function getTransactions(accno) {
    var from, to, selected=new Array();
    var transactionPool=new Array();
    transactionPool[0]=new createTrans("1/20/2015", "PPS Payment", "dr", 1300.5);
    transactionPool[1]=new createTrans("2/27/2015", "Online", "cr", 300.5);
    transactionPool[2]=new createTrans("1/11/2016", "ATM", "dr", 9300.0);
    transactionPool[3]=new createTrans("2/20/2016", "Counter", "dr", 300.5);
    transactionPool[4]=new createTrans("3/15/2016", "Online", "dr", 2200);
    transactionPool[5]=new createTrans("4/23/2016", "PPS Payment", "dr", 4300.99);
    transactionPool[6]=new createTrans("5/2/2016", "Counter", "cr", 7300.5);
    transactionPool[7]=new createTrans("6/5/2016", "Online", "dr", 500.5);
    transactionPool[8]=new createTrans("7/20/2016", "ATM", "cr", 800.3);
    transactionPool[9]=new createTrans("11/5/2016", "PPS Payment", "cr", 300.5);    
    from=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    to=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    for (i=0; i<to; i++) {
        selected[i]=transactionPool[from];
        from=(from+1)%9;
    }
    return selected; 
}


<script>window.onload = function () { 
document.getElementById("account").
innerHTML =  localStorage.accDetails;
var accDetail=getTransactions();
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = transactionPool[0];
}</script>
```

I write this in script to call the function but doesnt work. what's the problem with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, within your script tag there's no variable named transactionPool, since the reference to the returned array is named accDetail and not transactionPool, and transactionPool was (correctly) not a global variable.

Comment: so the code should be `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = accDetail.transactionPool[0];`?

Comment: or what is the correct way to call this function and return the desired value??

Comment: No, if the local reference to the array is accDetail, then the first element is accDetail[0].

Answer (score -1):

a little advice: do not use "new Array ()" but use "[ ]" to declare arrays!

```js
var list = [
  function(){ // 0
    return 'cat';
  },
  function(){ // 1
    return true
  },
  function(){ // 2
    return false;
  },
  function(){ // 3
    return 'food';
  }
];

// RUN!!
alert( list[2]() );
```

Comment: um, the function can't be changed as this is written by the lecturer, we have to call this function

Comment: to call the function just add "()". for example, "list [3] ()"

Comment: to return the array of test functions can return an array or an object. example:

in your function **return {sel : selected, transPool : transactionPool};**

After the selected value **accDetail.sel** or to get all the functions **accDetail.transPool**

Comment: Forse cercavi: inoltre acDetail è un array, quindi devi usare acDetail[0]
accDetail is also an array, so you must use **accDetail [0]**